# How do you get rid of page numbers on \part pages?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, page-numbering, parts

I am writing a book of puzzles in LaTeX, using the `book` class. The `\thispagestyle{empty}` command has successfully removed page numbers on all the `\chapter` pages, but so far no combination of `\newpage` and `\thispagestyle{empty}` before and/or after a `\part` command has been able to remove the page number at the center of the bottom of the `\part` page.

```
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\chapter{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

The code above produces a table of contents page, then a blank page, then a `\part` page, then a blank page, then a `\chapter` page. There are no page numbers except on the `\part` page, and it appears to be incredibly reluctant to disappear, as you can see from the number of empty page commands surrounding the `\part` command!

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a full MWE to show your situation (especially documentclass etc.)

Comment: If you're using `book` or `report` standard classes: Both apply `\thispagestyle{plain}` explicitly in the `\part` command, so `\thispagestyle{empty}` is useless here.

Answer (score 9):

The first page of a part or chapter explicitly uses the page style `plain`. If you want to change this behaviour, you can make `plain` to mean the same as `empty` by adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

After this, page style `plain` is no longer available. A more flexible solution is to define

```
\makeatletter
\let\origps@plain\ps@plain
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestyleEmpty{\let\ps@plain\ps@empty}
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestylePlain{\let\ps@plain\origps@plain}
\makeatother
```

Now you can equate `plain` with `empty` using `\MakePlainPagestyleEmpty` and revert it again by `\MakePlainPagestylePlain`.

Note that you can also switch the default page style using

```
 \pagestyle{empty}
```

and later switch back to

```
 \pagestyle{headings}
```

Try the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\let\origps@plain\ps@plain
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestyleEmpty{\let\ps@plain\ps@empty}
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestylePlain{\let\ps@plain\origps@plain}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\MakePlainPagestyleEmpty
\tableofcontents
\part{part}
\chapter{chapter}
\Blindtext

% Revert to standard behaviour of the book class
\chapter{chapter}
\MakePlainPagestylePlain
\pagestyle{headings}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using the `book` document class, all you need to do is issue the following two instructions in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
```

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\part}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Uno}
\chapter{A}
\part{Due}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I had `\xpatchcmd` in quite a similar way in my deleted post. (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I must confess I hadn't read your (deleted) posting closely before posting my own answer. Do you want to undelete yours (and I'll delete mine)?

Answer (score 3):

Though it's an old post I think I should add the solution that I found in TeX FAQ. The package `nonumonpart` is specially written for this purpose. One just needs to load this package as stated in the TeX FAQ.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{nonumonpart}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\part{}

\chapter{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is rather old, but I think it might be worth to add that there is another solution if one uses the KOMA script `scrbook` class.

As per Table 3.9 (page 83) of the [scrguide-en](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf), there is a macro to define the style of the part page. To set it to `empty`, one has to redefine `\partpagestyle` in the preamble as follows:

```tex
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using code suggested by the user manual of package [*sectsty*](https://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty): `\partfont{\thispagestyle{empty}}`

Comment: But if the `\partfont` was already defined to specify a particular font, this would override that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The question is "How do you get rid of page numbers on \part pages?", so I don't find this relevant

Comment: Indeed this will get rid of the page number, but it may also change the font used to set the title and text on the part page, which is probably not wanted.  However, since I'm not an experienced user of `sectsty`, it may contain a protection against such a change; I was just trying to offer a warning.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Aha, I understand now how you think: \partfont applies to everything on pages of type Part. However, this is not how the code works. If you read the [sectsty documentation, point 8.1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/sectsty/sectsty.pdf), you'll see that this should work, and that's is how I do. The _sectsy_ solution is a very neat and probably be the easiest solution.

IMO, my answer should hence be upvoted, not downvoted.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and pointer to the user guide.  I shall look into it, also the code.  (The `.cls` and `.sty` files I'm most familiar with don't work that way.  But I didn't downvote.)