# Remove page numbers on "Part" pages

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, books, parts

There are solutions out there.

Such as this one `\patchcmd{\part}{\vfil}{\vfil\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}` using `\usepackage{etoolbox}`

Or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359086/90984).

I've attempted to apply them to my code, but have failed to make it work so far.

Any insights as to why with a solution would be appreciated.

Thank you.

```
% PREAMBLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For links color
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox} % To make table footnote font smaller and quotes small
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{colortbl} % To define colors
\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

% HEADING and PART FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\partfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}

% STYLE PART WITH GRAPHICS AND WORK STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\bfseries\color{black}\filcenter\fontsize{60}{70}\partfont} % Size of Part
{\Huge\MakeUppercase\partfont\thepart}
{10pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-400pt)$) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};}

\begin{document}

\part{Part One}
\chapter{A}
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you already use command `\titleformat{\part}` to manipulate the `\part` page. Simply add there `\thispagestyle{empty}` to it like this:

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\bfseries\color{black}\filcenter\fontsize{60}{70}\partfont} % Size of Part
  {\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge\MakeUppercase\partfont\thepart} % <=========
  {10pt}
  {\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
    (0pt,-400pt)$) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};%
  }
```

Please see that I changed some of your other code marked with `<========`. For example you can not use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

together with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

or see that option `table` of `xcolor` loads package `colortbl` ...

So with the following complete and corrected MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <=============== not together with fontspec!
\special{papersize=215.9mm,279.4mm}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}\makeatother%

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % <==========================================
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage[rightmargin=0pt]{quoting}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{threeparttable} % For table notes + To allow footnote material to stay with the tabular environment
\usepackage{relsize} % To make table footnote font smaller and quotes small
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[linguistics,edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella} % Palatino clone

% HEADING and PART FONTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newfontfamily\partfont[]{TeX Gyre Heros}

% STYLE PART WITH GRAPHICS AND WORK STYLE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\bfseries\color{black}\filcenter\fontsize{60}{70}\partfont} % Size of Part
{\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge\MakeUppercase\partfont\thepart} % <=========
{10pt}
{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north) +
  (0pt,-400pt)$) {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};%
}


\begin{document}

\part{Part One}
\chapter{A}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter{B}
\chapter{C}
\end{document}
```

you get the following resulting part page after compiling with XeLaTeX:

[image: resulting part page]

As you can see the page number is gone (red circle) ...

Comment: Thank you. Works like a charm. Also got rid of 'fontenc' and have started to use 'colortbl'. Speaking of which, why do you suggest using 'colortbl'?

Comment: @CyanideBaby You missunderstand me. You allready called `colortbl` in your code, but if you add option `table` to `xcolor` the package `colortbl` gets loaded by `xcolor` ... So you can load both by using `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` ...