# Removing page number from the first page of new part

Tags: numbering, books

I am creating a book class document with several parts, each part containing several chapters. Now, the document is `openany`, so that the chapter may open on odd or even page. But each part has to open on an odd page, with a blank page following, and both pages should have no header or footer. I can get the empty page following a new part by adding `\cleardoublepage` and `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but the page number still appears on the opening page of the new part. The publisher doesn't want this. I am giving a minimal example below. How could I remove the page number from the opening page of a part?

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\part{Part One}\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{Part Two}\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum[2]
\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{Part Three}\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How do you get rid of page numbers on \part pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359079/134144)

Answer (score 3):

I think your best bet is to use the `memoir` class (**warning** I was the author). Here is an edited version of your MWE using the `openright` option so you don't need all those `\cleardoublepage` and simply changing the part pagestyle to `empty`.

```
% partprob2.tex  SE 517718  No page number on \part

\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty} % change the part pagestyle

\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\part{Part Two}%\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum[2]
%\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}
\part{Part Three}%\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The `memoir` class provides many more facilities than the `book` class. Use `texdoc memoir` to view the manual.

Comment: Thanks. I have not used the memoir class much, although I am trying it out for some of my own work. So, for production work, I continue to use the book class that I am more famliar with. I intend to shift to memoir soon.
Also, I don't want to use \openright because the chapters can start on any page. Only the parts need to open on an odd page.

Comment: @KadubaHouse In that case use the `openany` option and put `\cleardoublepage` before each `\part`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine `\part` because it uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` by default. Also, you can force `\cleardoublepage` in `\part` so you don't need to use `\cleardoublepage` every time. Chapters will still be `openany`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\part{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \thispagestyle{empty}% <<<<<<<<<<<
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \null\vfil
  \secdef\@part\@spart}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\lipsum[1]
\part{Part Two}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\lipsum[2]
\part{Part Three}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```