Why is the chapter number reset just before a new part, rather than after it?
I'm trying to place the chapter number in a header in a document of multiple \parts and reset the chapter counter within each part. The resetting works but the value of \thechapter in the last chapter before a new \part is set to 0.
If a \pagebreak is added just before the \part then the chapter number is correct.
Would you please tell me if this is the correct approach or if I'm doing something wrong, perhaps in the definition of the reset that makes it occur one chapter early?
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

If the parts look odd, it is because this document is two books in one, and only the second book has two parts.
Thank you.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
%  includeall,
%  ignoreheadfoot = true,
 inner = 1.5in,
 textwidth = 5.0in, % For title page only.
 textheight = 9in,
 headheight = 15pt
]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\let\origps@plain\ps@plain
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestyleEmpty{\let\ps@plain\ps@empty}
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestylePlain{\let\ps@plain\origps@plain}
\makeatother

\usepackage[newparttoc,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[bottomfloats]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\scshape #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\scshape #1}{}}

\fancyhfoffset{0pt}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\huge\vspace{3\baselineskip}}
{PART\nobreakspace\thepart.\vspace{15pt}\\
\rule[0.5ex]{0.35\textwidth}{1.2pt}\\%
\vspace{-10pt}
}
{0mm}
{}

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
{\centering\large\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{}{\vspace*{15pt}}}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\em\centering\partname~%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{First}{Second}.}\\\scshape}
{}
{\vspace{0pt}\\\centering\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1pt}}
[\vspace{10pt}]

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\fancypagestyle{myfancy}[fancy]{
\fancyhead[ER]{\textsc{Ch.} \thechapter}
}

\pagestyle{myfancy}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\pagebreak Page 2

% Without the following \pagebreak, \thechapter is set to 0 for Ch. 4.
\pagebreak
% \MakePlainPagestyleEmpty
\part{Part First}
% \MakePlainPagestylePlain

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Six}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Seven}
\pagebreak Page 2

% Without the following \pagebreak, \thechapter is set to 0 for Ch. 7.
\pagebreak
% \MakePlainPagestyleEmpty
\part{Part Second}
% \MakePlainPagestylePlain

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2

\end{document}

Added later:
I forgot the reason that I used the code to toggle between Empty and Plain, and that is because a new part always sets the page style to plain and ignores the current style and I didn't want page numbers on the part title pages. So, plain needs to be redefined before and after the part declaration.
The chapter counter can be reset to 0 at each new part. So, the code for both of these can be removed; and all that is really needed is a way in fancyhdr to vary the style of plain.
It's easy to set plain to fancy ( \fancypagestyle{plain}{} ) or make a style base on facny as did for myfancy; but I could not figure out how to set plain to empty or set myplain to plain, such as \fancypagestyle{myplain}[plain]{} or  \fancypagestyle{plain}[empty]{} and both throw a very vague error in Kile of "finished exit code 1."
But, since empty and plain are quite simple, I just defined them.
Is there a better way?
Thank you.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[newparttoc,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[bottomfloats]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\scshape #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\scshape #1}{}}

\fancyhfoffset{0pt}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\huge\vspace{3\baselineskip}}
{PART\nobreakspace\thepart.\vspace{15pt}\\
\rule[0.5ex]{0.35\textwidth}{1.2pt}\\%
\vspace{-10pt}
}
{0mm}
{}

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
{\centering\large\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{}{\vspace*{15pt}}}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\em\centering\partname~%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{First}{Second}.}\\\scshape}
{}
{\vspace{0pt}\\\centering\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1pt}}
[\vspace{10pt}]

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\fancypagestyle{myfancy}[fancy]{
\fancyhead[ER]{\textsc{Ch.} \thechapter}
}
\pagestyle{myfancy}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\pagebreak Page 2

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
}

\part{Part First}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}

\pagestyle{myfancy}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Six}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Seven}
\pagebreak Page 2

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
}
\part{Part Second}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2

\end{document}


the reset is fine. it's eschewing marks which is problematic ;).

This is basically the raison d'être of the marks system. Notice that the centre header, which uses \leftmark, still uses the correct chapter name. Only the right header, where you insert \thechapter rather than using a mark is incorrect.
The solution is to use a mark. Rather than leaving the right mark empty, you can use this to specify the format you want.
Note that it is better not to mix packages with explicit markup which encroaches on their domains. If you use fancyhdr, don't use the standard LaTeX markup for any page styles. If you want to specify ps@ etc. manually, don't use fancyhdr. Otherwise things just become hopelessly tangled. To control the appearance of blank and/or empty pages, see fancyhdr's documentation.
fancyhdr also has the best documentation I'm aware of on LaTeX's marks mechanism, not excepting coverage in books (I've read - obviously there are a lot more I haven't). It is not quite as clear as it was before the recent changes to the kernel, but it is still worth reading.
fancyhdr also allows you to define additional marks, should you need them1.
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[
  %  includeall,
  %  ignoreheadfoot = true,
  inner = 1.5in,
  textwidth = 5.0in, % For title page only.
  textheight = 9in,
  headheight = 15pt
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
% don't do this if you are using fancyhdr - see the manual and use its methods
\let\origps@plain\ps@plain
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestyleEmpty{\let\ps@plain\ps@empty}
\newcommand\MakePlainPagestylePlain{\let\ps@plain\origps@plain}
\makeatother

\usepackage[newparttoc,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[CE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{1pt}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\scshape #1}{\textsc{Ch.}~\thechapter}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
\markright{\scshape #1}{}}

\fancyhfoffset{0pt}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{chapter}{part}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\centering\huge\vspace{3\baselineskip}}
{PART\nobreakspace\thepart.\vspace{15pt}\\
  \rule[0.5ex]{0.35\textwidth}{1.2pt}\\%
  \vspace{-10pt}
}
{0mm}
{}

\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titlecontents{part}[0pt]
{\centering\large\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{}{\vspace*{15pt}}}
{\parbox[t][3ex][t]{\linewidth}{\em\centering\partname~%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\thecontentslabel}{I}}{First}{Second}.}\\\scshape}
{}
{\vspace{0pt}\\\centering\rule[0.5ex]{0.25\textwidth}{1pt}}
[\vspace{10pt}]

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\fancypagestyle{myfancy}[fancy]{%
  \fancyhead[ER]{\rightmark}%
}

\pagestyle{myfancy}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\pagebreak Page 2

% Without the following \pagebreak, \thechapter is set to 0 for Ch. 4.
% \pagebreak
% \MakePlainPagestyleEmpty
\thechapter
\part{Part First}
% \MakePlainPagestylePlain

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Three}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Four}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Five}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Six}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Seven}
\pagebreak Page 2

% Without the following \pagebreak, \thechapter is set to 0 for Ch. 7.
% \pagebreak
\thechapter
% \MakePlainPagestyleEmpty
\part{Part Second}
% \MakePlainPagestylePlain

\chapter{Chapter One}
\pagebreak Page 2
\chapter{Chapter Two}
\pagebreak Page 2

\end{document}

1LaTeX also now boasts a new marks mechanism. Eventually, this will doubtless be superior to anything a package can hope to do on top. So while I can't recommend it at the time this answer is written, note that this has probably changed if you're reading this a few years later.

Thank you. I think the empty page example is on page 27 of the fancyhdr documentation. I made note of it in my template preamble and used it for things like "page left intentionally blank." I think I tried this MakePlainPagestyleEmpty/Plain approach because of wanting the Part title pages to not have a page number, like chapter title pages do.  Got it from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359086/324837 and used it in the wrong context. I'll have to go back over fancy header and see how to do the same.

@Gary  Yes also note \ps@name requires you to define 4 commands \@oddhead \@oddevenhead and \@oddfooter \@evenfooter. These are used by ps@name. But as cfr said better not to mix the two. Either everything using fancyhdr  or fully utilizing LaTeX own methods.

@Gary I forget exactly, but something like \fancypagestyle{<name>}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}} where <name> is the style being applied to part pages. (but i haven't checked this - so don't quote me unless i happen to be right ;).)

I remember, now, the issue that started this off; for I did try to use fancyhdr's \fancypagestyle for this but the part code ignores the current page style and always uses plain, just as for chapter. So, plain has to be redefined to empty before the part declaration and reset afterward. I added an example at the end of my post. which eliminates the ps@... code and the reset of chapter. But it still seems a bit clumsy.

@Gary yes, but you can use fancyhdr to redefine the plain style.
